# Multiple join with SQL

Tags: sql, microsoft-query

I have a problem with my SQL query.
I want to have a multiple join, but the error is not helpful.

The following is my query:

```
SELECT bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE AS Id_client
    ,BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_NAME AS Nom_prenom
    ,PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS.PMP_MUNCIPCODE
FROM bn_ms_bm_bankmaster
INNER JOIN BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE ON bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE = BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_CUSTCODE
INNER JOIN PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS ON bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE = PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS.CMP_CUSTCODE
```

This query give back to me the flowing error:

> Impossible to add table bn_ms_bm_bankmaster with Microsoft Query

Any help will welcome.

Comment: So this is a SQL server?  Also can you just query that table by itself?  Do you have the same table named with different schema?  Try adding the schema to the table select

Comment: Maybe you're appointing to another schema?

Comment: What happens if you select only from bn_ms_bm_bankmaster without any join, does it work then?

Comment: Yes, without any join it works,

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
Select A.CMP_CUSTCODE AS Id_client,
B.CMP_NAME as Nom_prenom,
C.PMP_MUNCIPCODE

FROM bn_ms_bm_bankmaster AS A

INNER JOIN BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE AS B ON A.CMP_CUSTCODE= B.CMP_CUSTCODE
INNER JOIN PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS AS C ON B.CMP_CUSTCODE = C.CMP_CUSTCODE
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with below.

```
select * from(Select bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE AS Id_client,BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_NAME as Nom_prenom,PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS.PMP_MUNCIPCODE FROM bn_ms_bm_bankmaster INNER JOIN BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE ON bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE=BN_CS_MP_MASTERPROFILE.CMP_CUSTCODEINNER JOIN PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS ON bn_ms_bm_bankmaster.CMP_CUSTCODE=PR_GN_AD_ENTITYADDRESS.CMP_CUSTCODE);
```

Comment: When I don't use the other join it works but when I use multiple join then ERROR

Comment: ERROR: Impossible to add the table '(SELECT with Microsoft Query

Comment: Can you define As for internal select. as below

select * from (your_query) X;  and try again